# Azure function cannot access WCF service which hosted in Internal windows server

Tags: .net, visual-studio, azure, wcf, azure-functions

I have created Azure HTTP Trigger function with .Net framework on Visual Studio. In that function it invoke wcf service which hosted in our internal windows server. I hosted function in localhost(using visual studio) and call the function URL using postman without issue and it has called the WCF service successfully.
But After deploying azure and when I'm testing the function I got below error.

There was no endpoint listening at https://dev_service.ca/ourservice.svc that could accept the message.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with your web.config file. That it is configured to use the address localhost.

It could also be that you have not turned on https for your app service.